# Crashlytics Linker Error after Teammate Updated Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, crashlytics

A teammate updated the Crashlytics framework within our project via the Fabric application. When I pull the project repo and try to build, I receive the following error:

Framework not found Crashlytics
Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

This error did not occur before the update. We have tried to remove Crashlytics from the project and copy the framework files back in, but this doesn't help.

The project still runs on my teammates computer without any issue. Our project is iOS/Objective-C. Any ideas?

Comment: Alex here from Fabric. Can you try a project clean and build?

Comment: Hey Alex, cleaning and building did not work. The solution found in the twittercommunity page, post as an answer, did work. Thank  you.